# Manipulate child elements with xPath in PHP

Tags: php, xpath

I have a XML document with an element (named `region`) that may or may not have multiple child elements. For my import i need to make sure that there is only one child element. If there are more child elements, i need to remove all children, except the last one. The following situations can occur:

```
 // Option 1: No child elements
 <property name="region">
 </property>

 // Option 2: One child element
 <property name="region">
 <value>Bottom</value>
 </property>

 // Option 3: Two child elements
 <property name="region">
 <value>Top</value>
 <value>Bottom</value>
 </property>

 // Option 4: Three child elements
 <property name="region">
 <value>Top</value>
 <value>Middle</value>
 <value>Bottom</value>
 </property>
```

What i need is to filter the XML to re-format the child elements of the `region` element to always have one child element (`value`) with ether the last child element's value or if there are no children, the value 'none'.

My desired output would be the following:

```
 // For Option 1
 <property name="region">
 <value>none</value>
 </property>

 // For option 2, 3 & 4
 <property name="region">
 <value>Bottom</value>
 </property>
```

I know i can select the `region` property with the xPath query `//property[@name = "region"]`, but i don't know how to manipulate the children from there.

I have the following code when i get stuck

```
 <?php
 $xml = '<properties>
      <property name="region">
      </property>

      <property name="region">
      <value>Bottom</value>
      </property>

      <property name="region">
      <value>Top</value>
      <value>Bottom</value>
      </property>

      <property name="region">
      <value>Top</value>
      <value>Middle</value>
      <value>Bottom</value>
      </property>
 </properties>';
 $document = new DOMDocument();
 $document->loadXML($xml);
 $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
 foreach($xpath->query('//property[@name = "region"]') as $node){

      // Now i need something like below, but i can't find a way to make it work
      if $node->hasChildren()
           Remove all but last child
      else
           Create child element with text none
 }
```

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with a twisted nested `for` Loop in conjunction with with `getElementByTagName()` of the `DOMElement` Class. Here's how:

```
<?php
    $xml = '<properties>
      <property name="region">
      </property>

      <property name="region">
      <value>Bottom</value>
      </property>

      <property name="region">
      <value>Top</value>
      <value>Bottom</value>
      </property>

      <property name="region">
      <value>Top</value>
      <value>Middle</value>
      <value>Bottom</value>
      </property>
 </properties>';

    $document           = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadXML($xml);
    $xpath              = new DOMXpath($document);

    foreach($xpath->query('//property[@name = "region"]') as $node){
        /**@var DOMElement $node*/
        // CHECK IF THE $node HAS CHILD NODES USING $node->getElementsByTagName("value")->length PROPERTY
        // WHICH RETURNS THE NUMBER OF CHILD NODES
        $numChildNodes      = $node->getElementsByTagName("value")->length;

        // IF THE CURRENT NODE HAS AT LEAST 1 CHILD, LOOP THROUGH THE CHILDREN
        // AND REMOVE THE CHILD NODES...EXCEPT FOR THE LAST CHILD NODE...
        if($numChildNodes > 0){
            $cuePoint       = ($numChildNodes - 1);

            // LOOP THROUGH ALL CHILD-NODES OF THE CURRENT NODE AND REMOVE ALL CHILD NODES
            // EXCEPT FOR THE LAST CHILD NODE...
            for($index=0; $index<$numChildNodes; $index++){
                if($index !== $cuePoint ) {
                    $currentNode    = $node->getElementsByTagName("value")->item($index);
                    // REMOVE THIS NODE...
                    $node->removeChild($currentNode);
                }
            }
        }else{
            // IF THE CURRENT NODE HAS NO CHILD AT ALL,
            // SIMPLY CREATE AN ELEMENT NODE AND APPEND IT IN THE RIGHT CONTEXT...
            // HERE WE ARE USING none AS DEFAULT BUT YOU CAN USE WHATEVER
            // STRING YOU PLEASE ...
            $newElementNode     = new DOMElement("value", "none", "");
            $node->appendChild($newElementNode);
        }
    }
    $document->save("abc.xml");
    var_dump($document);
```

The **abc.xml** File should look similar to this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <properties>
        <property name="region">
        <value>none</value>
        </property>

        <property name="region">
        <value>Bottom</value>
        </property>

        <property name="region">          
        <value>Bottom</value>
        </property>

        <property name="region">          
        <value>Bottom</value>         
        </property>
     </properties>
```

While the result of `var_dump($document);` should produce something similar to this:

```
    object(DOMDocument)[1]
      public 'doctype' => null
      public 'implementation' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'documentElement' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'actualEncoding' => null
      public 'encoding' => null
      public 'xmlEncoding' => null
      public 'standalone' => boolean true
      public 'xmlStandalone' => boolean true
      public 'version' => string '1.0' (length=3)
      public 'xmlVersion' => string '1.0' (length=3)
      public 'strictErrorChecking' => boolean true
      public 'documentURI' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/poiz/so/' (length=34)
      public 'config' => null
      public 'formatOutput' => boolean false
      public 'validateOnParse' => boolean false
      public 'resolveExternals' => boolean false
      public 'preserveWhiteSpace' => boolean true
      public 'recover' => boolean false
      public 'substituteEntities' => boolean false
      public 'nodeName' => string '#document' (length=9)
      public 'nodeValue' => null
      public 'nodeType' => int 9
      public 'parentNode' => null
      public 'childNodes' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'firstChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'lastChild' => string '(object value omitted)' (length=22)
      public 'previousSibling' => null
      public 'attributes' => null
      public 'ownerDocument' => null
      public 'namespaceURI' => null
      public 'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'localName' => null
      public 'baseURI' => string '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/poiz/so/' (length=34)
      public 'textContent' => string '

                none

                Bottom

                Bottom

                Bottom

         ' (length=146)
```

Hope this here could give you an idea on how to do it best on your own.

Cheers and Good Luck!!!

Comment: That is exactly what i need! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Each node has a property named `childNodes` that has a `length` property which means you can have number of children nodes of current node this way. But since white-spaces are considered as a single node themselves you should initialize another query and subtract them from `childNodes->length`.

This solution is correct but is not the best as we are able to make it short:

```
$xpath->query('./*', $node)->length > 1
```

This means all element nodes within the current node (not white-spaces). After finding elements with more than one element child, we are nearly done:

```
./*[position() < last()]
```

Which means all children with position less than last one within current node. We are able to remove them easily afterward. Here is your modified `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($query as $node){
    if ($xpath->query('./*', $node)->length > 1) {
        $children = $xpath->query('./*[position() < last()]', $node);
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $child->parentNode->removeChild($child);
        }
    }
}
```

You can confirm output by saving modifications:

```
echo $document->saveXML();
```